# Neo4j - Traversing from one node to another which are indirectly connected by parent Node

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have a specific Case where i have two labels Person and Company.
Person has two nodes X and Y and Company has a Single Node.
Both persons have a relationship with Company HAS_EMPLOYEE.

I want to Find Relationship Between X and Y i.e. they work for the same Company.

How to do that in Neo4j? Given only Nodes X and Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on if you're looking for a specific connection (via a :Company node), or just looking for any connection at all.

Let's say :Person nodes have a name, and that person nodes X and Y have the names 'x' and 'y', so we can match to them. Let's also say that you have an index on :Person(name) so we can lookup the nodes quickly.

If the query we want is "do persons x and y share the same company", the query for this, returning the company in question, is:

```
match (x:Person{name:'x'})<-[:HAS_EMPLOYEE]-(comp:Company)-[:HAS_EMPLOYEE]->(y:Person{name:'y'})
return comp
```

But if we don't know how these persons are connected, or even if they're connected, then we'll likely want to run a `shortestPath()` match between the nodes, and see what connects them.

It helps to set an upper bounds for this match. For now let's use 8 hops max.

```
match path=shortestPath((x:Person{name:'x'})-[*..8]-(y:Person{name:'y'}))
return path
```

Comment: I was looking for the shortest path that is we don't know that there is company that relates them. Perfect answer.